# How to populate a private container for unit test?

Tags: python, testing, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class that defines a private (well, `__container` to be exact since it is python) container.  I am using the information within said container as part of the logic of what the class does and have the ability to add/delete the elements of said container.

For unit tests, I need to populate this container with some data. That
data depends on the test done and thus putting it all in setUp() would
be impractical and bloated -- plus it could add unwanted side effects.

Since the data is private, I can only add things via the public
interface of the object.  This runs code that need not be run during a
unit test and in some cases is just a copy and paste from another test.

Currently, I am mocking the whole container but somehow it does not feel that elegant a solution.  Due to Python mocking frame work ([mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html)), this requires the container to be public -- so I can use `patch.dict()`.  I would rather keep that data private.

**What pattern can one use to still populate the containers without excercising the public method so I have data to test with?**

Is there a way to do this with [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html)'s `patch.dict()` that I missed?

Comment: You explictly don't need to make anything public. You can access `_private` members and `__name_mangeled` ones as well (the latter requires knowledge of the name mangling algorithm though, and is even more fragile). **That doesn't mean you should though**.

Comment: @delnan: Indeed, you could write: `patch.object(sut._ClassName__container, {...})` and that would do it.  That would be a solution.  If you wanted to write it up, I'd upvote you...

Comment: I won't submit it as answer because it isn't a good answer. It technically answers your question and it's worth mentioning, but it doesn't solve your *actual* problem. I'd write up what I feel you should do instead, but I lack time and test guru-ness.

Comment: I don't understand the question completely, but will the @property decorators help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until recently, I would have just pointed you at plenty of other existing questions that say that you generally shouldn't need access to any private stuff, in order to write unit tests - as the whole point of tests is to test the public (and protected) interface.

For example, in the question [how to unit-test private methods in jquery plugins?](http://how%20to%20unit-test%20private%20methods%20in%20jquery%20plugins?), there is [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750279/how-to-unit-test-private-methods-in-jquery-plugins/5750458#5750458)

> The same applies here as with any other language and testing privates: **To test private methods, you should exercise them via the public interface**. In other words, by calling your public methods, the private methods get tested in the process because the public methods rely on the privates.
>
> Generally private methods are not tested separately from the public interface - the entire point is that they are implementation details, and tests should generally not know too much about the specifics of the implementation

In your specific case, you say:

> Since the data is private, I can only add things via the public interface of the object. This run codes that need not be run during a unit test and in some case is just a copy and paste from another test.

I would be cautious about having any tests that avoided code that normally needs to be run - for fear that your tests would spuriously pass, due to some difference between the test behaviour and the real world.

Having said all that, I recently learned about a really excellent article on writing testsuite called **[The Way of Testivus](http://www.agitar.com/downloads/TheWayOfTestivus.pdf)**. It's a PDF that's only 12 pages long, and a really easy and enjoyable read.

What's relevant here is the section entitled "Sometimes, the test justifies the means" - in the context of violating encapsulation to enable testing. I highly recommend it.

(Another favourite of mine is "An ugly test is better than no test.")

So, in your context, if you still decide you really want a different way to set up data purely for tests, it might be reasonable to add a public setter method, specifically documented as only existing to aid writing of tests.

Comment: You misunderstood the question.  I can test `__container` via the public interface, that is fine and indeed what you should do.  However, I need to populate it to run other tests.  Should I populate it via the public interface (clutter and copy and paste anti-patterns) or do I mock the private container or what else?  The what else is what I want to know.  Otherwise, just a best practice would be fine.

Comment: I'm tempted to give you -1 for the part about reducing the quality of your code for the sake of unit testing

Comment: Please understand that I was quoting from a publication (Testivus) and then read that for yourself! It really is an enjoyable and interesting read.

Answer (score 0):

The convention for private attributes is a single leading underscore; a double leading underscore is for protected (it will use name mangling to keep the attribute unique across subclasses).

```
class Test():
    _private = 1
    __protected = dict()
    __container = list()
```

If private is what you really want, just remove one of the leading underscores and then accessing and modifying `_container` is easy-peasy.

If protected is really what you want, you can still access `__container` but you'll have to mangle the name yourself if accessing it from outside the class.  Using my `Test` class above to illustrate:

```
t = Test()
t.__Test_container.append("this is how it's done")
```